# fiveam: fail to understand why this test fails

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

So I'm at a loss as to why this test fails. When I run the statements in the repl everything appears to work correctly but the fiveam test fails.

There is a test case in the following gist: https://gist.github.com/PuercoPop/5765844

the fiveam test fails with the following message. I don't understand why the second board is displayed differently (with new lines):

```
EXPECTED-BOARD evaluated to (:EMPTY :|2| :|3| :|4| :|5| :|6| :|7| :|8| :|9|),  
which is not EQUAL to (:EMPTY
                       :|2|
                       :|3|
                       :|4|
                       :|5|
                       :|6|
                       :|7|
                       :|8|
                       :|9|)..
```

Comment: Yeah that is correct, irc told me. Reply as an answer if you want the karma btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying constant data. Weird things are allowed to happen when you modify constant data. If there's even half a chance you'll be unleashing a destructive function (as in "modify the data...") create your lists using `(list ...)` instead of `'(...)`.